# Adding alternating pairs of adjacent columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data.frame of Republican and Democratic votes for the presidency by year -- e.g., R2020, D2020, R2016, D2016, etc.  I have entries for all 3108 counties, for 30 elections, so it is a 3108 x 61 data.frame, with the first column being a labels column.  I am looking to get total votes by year for  each county.  E.g., something to this effect:

```
- New_df[1, 1] = df [1, 2] + df [1, 3] 
- New_df[1, 2] = df [1,4] + df [1, 5] 
- New_df[1, 3] = df [1, 6] + df [ 1, 7]
. . .

- New_df[3108, 30] = df[3108, 60] + df[3108, 61]
```

I could use the following code, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this while avoiding the ugly nested for loops.

```
for(i in 1: ncol(df)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df)){
    k <- i * 2
    new_df[j, i] <- df[j, k] + df[j, k + 1]  
  }
}
```

Here is a dput of the first 15 rows and 9 columns (including the label column) of the data.frame:

```
structure(list(county = c("Adams", "Allen", "Ashland", "Ashtabula", 
"Athens", "Auglaize", "Belmont", "Brown", "Butler", "Carroll", 
"Champaign", "Clark", "Clermont", "Clinton", "Columbiana"), r2016 = c(8659L, 
30487L, 17493L, 23318L, 11354L, 18658L, 21108L, 14573L, 106976L, 
9254L, 12631L, 35205L, 67518L, 13838L, 31676L), d2016 = c(2326L, 
13294L, 5740L, 15577L, 16370L, 3980L, 8785L, 4353L, 58642L, 3154L, 
4594L, 23328L, 26715L, 4066L, 12432L), d2012 = c(3976L, 17914L, 
8281L, 23803L, 18307L, 5831L, 14156L, 7107L, 62388L, 5543L, 7044L, 
31297L, 30458L, 5791L, 19821L), r2012 = c(6865L, 29502L, 15519L, 
18298L, 8543L, 17169L, 16758L, 11916L, 105176L, 7315L, 11045L, 
31820L, 64208L, 12009L, 25251L), d2008 = c(4170L, 19522L, 9300L, 
25027L, 20722L, 6738L, 16302L, 7503L, 66030L, 6423L, 7385L, 31958L, 
31611L, 6558L, 21882L), r2008 = c(6914L, 29940L, 15158L, 18949L, 
9742L, 16414L, 15422L, 12192L, 105341L, 7097L, 11141L, 33634L, 
62559L, 12409L, 25585L), r2004 = c(7653L, 32580L, 16209L, 21038L, 
10847L, 17016L, 15589L, 12647L, 109872L, 7695L, 11718L, 34941L, 
62949L, 12938L, 25753L), d2004 = c(4281L, 16470L, 8576L, 24060L, 
18998L, 5903L, 17576L, 7140L, 56243L, 6300L, 6968L, 33535L, 25887L, 
5417L, 23429L)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you use `dput()` on, say, the first 20 or 50 rows of your dataframe? That would make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: I did it and have the output copied to my clipboard, but I've never done it to input data here before -- is there a primer on how to do it in a way that doesn't offend the formatting requirements of the site?

Comment: Apologies if I didn't do that correctly.

Comment: Dan, I think I accidentally deleted your response (or you did purposely). I am so sorry. I wanted to comment and say that transforming long was super clever, and to thank you for that.

Comment: I still see my response. Did you accidentally flag it? Anyway, I'm glad the solution works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with data I made up:

```
df <-data.frame(
  County = rep(LETTERS,4),
  Party = rep(c(rep("R",26),rep("D",26)),2),
  Year = c(rep(2020,52), rep(2016,52)),
  Votes = rpois(104,1000)
)
library(tidyverse)
df_wide <- pivot_wider(df,names_from = c(Party,Year),values_from = Votes, names_sep = "")
head(df_wide)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  County R2020 D2020 R2016 D2016
  <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 A        996   988   931  1043
2 B        995  1002  1005   984
3 C        980  1017   998  1015
4 D       1035   993  1048   953
5 E       1007  1004   955   980
6 F        970   997   982   992
```

I think your dataset looks something like that. Now you can use `dplyr` to get what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
total_df <- df_wide %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -County, names_to = "Party_Year", values_to = "Votes") %>%
  mutate(Party = substring(Party_Year,1,1),
         Year = as.numeric(substring(Party_Year,2,5))) %>%
  group_by(Year,County) %>%
  summarize(Total_Votes = sum(Votes))
head(total_df)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   Year [1]
   Year County Total_Votes
  <dbl> <chr>        <int>
1  2016 A             1974
2  2016 B             1989
3  2016 C             2013
4  2016 D             2001
5  2016 E             1935
6  2016 F             1974
```

EDIT: Here it is with the dataframe you gave:

```
library(tidyverse)
total_df <- your_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -county, names_to = "Party_Year", values_to = "Votes") %>%
  mutate(Party = substring(Party_Year,1,1),
         Year = as.numeric(substring(Party_Year,2,5))) %>%
  group_by(Year,county) %>%
  summarize(Total_Votes = sum(Votes))
head(total_df)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   Year [1]
   Year county    Total_Votes
  <dbl> <chr>           <int>
1  2004 Adams           11934
2  2004 Allen           49050
3  2004 Ashland         24785
4  2004 Ashtabula       45098
5  2004 Athens          29845
6  2004 Auglaize        22919
```